# Dealing with saved epoch times when clocks change

Tags: java, android, alarm, epoch

I have an alarm clock app that uses the following two methods:

```
private void fastForwardAlarmToNext24Hours() { 
// Get Alarm Time (unix)
    DataStorageController alarmTimeController = new DataStorageController(getApplicationContext());
    epochAlarmTime = alarmTimeController.getAlarmTime();

    // Get Current Time (unix)
    long epochCurrentTime = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L;

    // While Alarm Time in the past, fast forward another 24 hours
    while (epochAlarmTime < epochCurrentTime) {
        epochAlarmTime = epochAlarmTime + (24*60*60); // Add a days worth of seconds
    }
}

private Long getNumberOfSecondsUntilAlarm() {
    long epochCurrentTime = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L;
    return epochAlarmTime - epochCurrentTime;
}
```

This works fine and I get these sorts of results back:

SUMMER

10-12 07:46:26.678: D/CJS Logging(776): epochCurrentTime: 1381560386  10/12/2013 7:46:26 AM +1
10-12 07:46:26.678: D/CJS Logging(776): epochAlarmTime: 1381560480 10/12/2013 7:48:00 AM +1

However, when I forward the datetime of my device to the winter (post clocks change), I get the following result and the alarm fires 1 hour off:

WINTER

11-12 07:47:10.441: D/CJS Logging(942): epochCurrentTime: 1384242430  11/12/2013 7:47:10 AM +0
11-12 07:47:10.441: D/CJS Logging(942): epochAlarmTime: 1384325280  11/13/2013 6:48:00 AM +0

The reason this is happening is because the saved alarm time remains the same epoch time but when the clocks change that moves the local time by 1 hour.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to deal with this?

Cheers, Charlie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using UNIX time, you may want to use local time instead, using `Calendar` instances:

```
// Get Current Time 
Calendar currentTime = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();

// While Alarm Time in the past, fast forward a day
while (alarmTime.before(currentTime)) {
    alarmTime.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
}
```

Comment: Hi Yuku - think this looks like a great option.  Just one question: how would I then form the method getNumberOfSecondsUntilAlarm() ? Cheers, Charlie

Answer (score 0):

Can you register for

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_TIME_CHANGED

and update your next firing time?

Answer (score 0):

The long value returned by System.currentTimeMillis() is always the the number of seconds after January 1, 1970 UTC.

Depending on how you initialize the timestamp, different values can displayed ( based on your locale/ machine / time etc ).

To keep it consistent, deal with your times internally using GMT ( or a timezone that does not have daylight savings ).